# NIO - How to make SelectionKey to be interested in NO opts

Tags: java, selector, nio

How do you make `java.nio.channels.SelectionKey` to be interested in NO opts?

`SelectionKey#cancel()` has possibility but is not so good, because it makes the key useless.

`SelectionKey` has `interestOps` constants; `OP_ACCEPT`, `OP_CONNECT`, `OP_READ` and `OP_WRITE`, but not `OP_NOTHING`.
Then is it legal operation to call `SelectionKey#interestOpts(**0**)`?

Here is an example.

```
for(;;) {
    selector.select();
    for (Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            it.hasNext();) {
        SelectionKey key = it.next(); it.remove();
        key.interestOps(0);     // interested in no opts.

        // another thread handles socket...
        worker.handle();
    }
    updateKeys();     // if the worker completes handling,
                      // other interestOpts are set...
}
```

This code works for me so far, but I doubt it is legal to call `SelectionKey#interestOpts(0)`.
Or could you tell me your best practice?

Comment: yes, 0 is way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I doubt it is legal to call SelectionKey#interestOpts(0)

Why? Where does it say that in the Javadoc?

It's perfectly legal. You've answered your own question.

Comment: I understand your question.

Comment: Because the Javadoc doesn't mention it.

I think there is a big difference between to set bits and to clear bits.

`SelectionKey` and the classes around don't have a such method in order to clear bits, and besides, the Javadoc doesn't mention it.
So I'm puzzled how to do.

Comment: Err, the Javadoc says 'sets this key's interest set to the given value'. Not excluding zero. And if your question isn't whether it is legal, but how to do it, you have already answered it yourself. This isn't making much sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot get what you mean. I'd like to know the legal way to make `SelectionKey` to be interested in no opts.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot get what on earth you mean by 'cannot get what you mean'. I have now told you twice that what you asked about is legal. That's the answer to your question.